# Points shapefile resulting in MultiPoints table in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, shapefile, geometry, multipoint

I have a Points shapefile. When opened with QGIS, the type is 'Point' (right-click on the layer and check properties). When imported in PostGIS using pgAdmin III plugin 'PostGIS shapefile and DBF loader', the created table is of Multi Point type... I can't change the type afterwards and this brings issues like updating other Points tables geometry column.

Any idea on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution by clicking the `Generate simple geometries instead of MULTI geometries` in the options dialog of pgAdmin III import plugin:

[image]